# Unable to refetchevents when updating or editing events using ajax modal. Fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, fullcalendar

My problem is i'm unable to live edit the event after ajax success. Wnen i edit the event, the data will be updated in the database but it doesn't make any changes in the calendar display.

So i have to refresh the whole page first in order to take effect the updated event.

I've also tried some of the answers I've searched. Like this one:

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEventSource', events);
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', events);         
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
```

And this one:

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent',id);
```

Or this:

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEvents',id); --> this will remove the event displayed in calendar
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents');   --> but it doesn't refetch the event.
```

None of these seems to work for me.

I've been searching for about two days now, but no luck. I've also searched for others that got answered but all of them doesn't work for me. BTW, the add event and delete event is working properly. Only the edit event isn't.

Here is my full code:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
          header: {
          left: 'today add_event',
          center: 'prev title next',
          right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
          },
          eventOrder: 'start',
          editable: true,
          eventLimit: true,
          selectable: true,
          allDaySlot: false,
          selectHelper: true,
          select: function(start, end) {
              $('#ModalAdd #start').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
              $('#ModalAdd #end').val(moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
              $('#ModalAdd').modal('show');
          },
          eventRender: function(event, element) {
              element.bind('dblclick', function() {
              $('#myModaledit #id').val(event.id);
              $('#myModaledit #title').val(event.title);
              $('#myModaledit #start').val(moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
              $('#myModaledit #end').val(moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
              $('#myModaledit').modal('show');
              });
           },
          eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
              edit(event);
            },
          eventResize: function(event,dayDelta,minuteDelta,revertFunc) {
              edit(event);
            },
          events: [
          <?php 
            foreach($events as $event): 
                $start = explode(" ", $event['start']);
                $end = explode(" ", $event['end']);
            if($start[1] == '00:00:00'){
                $start = $start[0];
            }else{
                $start = $event['start'];
                                  }
            if($end[1] == '00:00:00'){
                $end = $end[0];
            }else{
                $end = $event['end'];
            }?>
            {
            id: '<?php echo $event['id']; ?>',
            title: '<?php echo $event['title']; ?>',
            start: '<?php echo $start; ?>',
            end: '<?php echo $end; ?>',
            },
          <?php endforeach;?>
            ],
        });

        $('#myFormAdd').on('submit', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                doAdd();
         });

        $('#myFormEdit').on('submit', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                doEdit();
         });

         $('#deleteButton').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                doDelete();
         );

        function doAdd(){
           var title = $('#title').val();
           var start = $('#start').val();
           var endTime2 = $('#end').val();

           $.ajax({
               url: 'addEvent.php',
               data: 'action=add&title='+title+'&start='+start+'&end='+end,
               type: "POST",
               success: function(json) {
                   $("#calendar").fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                   {
                       id: json.id,
                       title: title,
                       start: start,
                       end: end,
                   },
                   true);
                   alert('Added Successfully!');
               }
               });
            }

        function doEdit(){
           var id = $('#id').val();
           var title = $('#title').val();
           var start = $('#start').val();
           var end = $('#end').val();

           $.ajax({
               url: 'editEvent.php',
               data: 'action=update&id='+id+'&title='+title+'&start='+start+'&end='+end,
               type: "POST",
               success: function(json) {
                if(json == 1){                     
                   $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEvents',id);
                   $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents');
                   alert('Edited Successfully!'); 
                }
                else
                    return false;
                }                   
                });
             }

        function doDelete(){
               $("#myModaledit").modal('hide');
               var id = $('#id').val();
               $.ajax({
                   url: 'editEvent.php',
                   data: 'action=delete&id='+id,
                   type: "POST",
                   success: function(json) {
                       if(json == 1){
                            $("#calendar").fullCalendar('removeEvents',id);
                            alert("Deleted successfully!");
                       }
                       else
                            return false;
                   }
               });
           }
        });
```

Comment: Use the API the way it was designed: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/updateEvent

Comment: I'm sorry @RandyCasburn, what do you mean? i'm really just a newbee. My only problem is unable to refetch the events ufter edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "RefetchEvents" method isn't doing anything because you have a static data source. You load it once when the page is created, and run some PHP which turns the event data into a JavaScript array and embeds it directly into your calendar config. From JavaScript/fullCalendar's point of view this is a one-off, unchanging array.

There's no way for fullCalendar to find new events from your server. For that to work you'd have to create a separate PHP script (e.g. called "getEvents.php" or something)  which does nothing but return the latest event data for the calendar as JSON. Then you'd set the events option in the calendar as

```
events: "getEvents.php"
```

That way it can make a fresh ajax request to that script every time the events need updating (such as when `refetchEvents` is called).

See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed for details. note that fullCalendar automatically sends "start" and "end" parameters (which represent the earliest and latest dates the calendar is currently showing) and your PHP script is expected to only return events which fall between those dates. It will call this script again whenever you move to a new time period on the calendar.

Note that there is no need to call "removeEvent" just before you call "refetchEvents". "refetchEvents" will refresh any and all events on the calendar, so you don't need to worry about removing anything beforehand.

Comment: Thank you, you made it so clear for me to understand. I will try what you adviced. Also i tried what @Randy Casburn said, to put my update inside "eventClick: " so that i can use "updateEvent". Right now im almost done with it. I can now update without refresh inside "eventClick: function". I hope it won't have any problem in future. I will post an answer as soon as i completed it. So that others may see and get some idea in it.

Comment: Great. BTW if you are using "updateEvent" to directly update the calendar on the client-side then you will not need to do "refetchEvents" as well after you save your event. So in that respect my answer is an alternative to Randy's. But still it's better to have a dynamic source of events in any case

Comment: Thank you so much @ADyson, you are very helpful. I can now refetchevents after ajax success. I'd changed my old "events: " by this "events : 'getEvents.php', " and made a separate php script retrieving all events in database. That is awsome.